# How to write 'after next tuesday at 11:59PM' in mysql 'where' clause

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

I've found this difficult to search for because the requirements are sort of ambiguous, but what I'm after is I'd like to have a where clause in a mysql query that is:

```
where START_DATE > next Tuesday at 11:59 PM
```

I'm using this for Crystal Reports and want the report to be dynamic to where it can be run on any day without needing to change any report date parameters.  I also need to know how to build the query in a way that would allow the report to be run on Tuesday itself as well.

I always prefer to get everything that I can out of the query itself rather than mucking about in the select expert.

This is my first question posted on the site - feedback for improvement is welcomed.

Comment: So if where run on Tuesday would next Tuesday be in 7 days or 14 days?

Comment: It would be within the next seven days.

Answer (score 1):

That's a fun one if you are in the mood I guess, in any case please see this link:

http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=20512

or this link:

http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/99-Finding-Next-Monday-using-MySQL-Dates.html

Comment: Thank you - these look very promising - I just need to take some time to wrap my head around them...